# Participation in Tags?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Currently it seems that people (on the main site) are listed as not having participated in any tags.  (This seems to be the case for me, and for JDH; I didn't check any others.)  Is this a temporary thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Badges and tags are processed on a rolling basis, and I don't think we should worry about anything related to these until 24 hours have passed.

Comment: Dear Scott, Thanks for the explanation.  Cheers, Matt